# Inserting subviews from other classes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to add UIImageView subviews to my viewController.view, with consideration for whether they go above or below an image.

Basically, my viewController has an image of a body. I allow the user to add accessories to the scene, for example a hat. I need to put some of these images above, some below the body view index.

However I'm having trouble figuring out how to add the image behind the body. I figured I could try and create a UIImageView property as a reference point on the viewController and do something like this:

```
 //this is from my menuItem class which has a UIViewController property connecting it to the main scene
[self.viewController.view insertSubview:sprite belowSubview:self.viewController.body];
```

However this code doesn't work, as I get the warning `"Property body not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'"`, even though I @property and @synthesize it.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or have a better design on how to implement this? Thanks

@shubhank:

```
  //.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImageView *body;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)  UIImageView *body;

 //.m (in viewDidLoad)
 self.body = [[UImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 300, 339, 562)];
    self.body.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"body.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:body];
```

Comment: add the code of how is body defined in interface section in your project to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Solved:**

Silly issue. I simply needed to forward declare my ViewController class in my MenuItem class, rather than use UIViewController *.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`[self.view insertSubview:sprite belowSubview:body]`. Don't insert `viewController` after `self`, 'cause `self` IS `viewController`.

Comment: Hi, I mentioned that I property and synthesize it. Is that not enough? [at]property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *body;

Comment: Oh, my bad - [self.view insertSubview:sprite belowSubview:body]. Don't insert viewController after self, 'cause self IS viewController.

Comment: Hi, I can't do that from this class. I'm instantiating the image from my MenuItem class (UIImageView subclass) which are nestled in a scroll view. I can make it appear in the viewController with [self.viewController.view addSubview:sprite], now its just the matter of figuring out how to add it below the body.

Comment: Could you post some code? Looks like you messed up the structure a bit.

Comment: Sure, what part would you like to see? My viewController simply adds the body subview, as well as creates a scrollview with two menuItems in it. When a menuItem gets touched, it instantiates the sprite. I have no problems adding sprites to the viewController with "addSubview", but I need to add them to the viewController behind the body imageview.

Answer (score 0):

there is two things happening that i can't seem to understand.

```
[self.viewController.view insertSubview:sprite belowSubview:self.viewController.body]
```

**Here you are accessing body by self.viewController.body**

and then  where body is defined

```
[self.view addSubview:body]
```

**so how come you can access it both by view controller and self.view.**

There is something wrong here..

Also

```
 self.body = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 300, 339, 562)];
```

change it to

```
 self.body = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 300, 339, 562)]autorelease];
```

the property retains the UIImage view..you should release it.

Comment: do you have a variable defined viewController?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am instantiating the body in my viewController class. I'm instantiating the sprites however, in a separate class called "MenuItem". MenuItem is an imageView subclass. When the user touches a menuItem on the screen, it instantiates the graphic (ie. hat) onto the viewController.view.

*Edit: Yes, menuItem has a property called viewController which gets defined by the viewController (menuItem.viewController = self) when I'm creating the menuItems.

Comment: adding code to the main view from the menu item is a bad practice...what you should do is save the sprite as a property in menu item class..make it available as an instance method...in main view get the sprite using Menuitem instance..and then add it to the view in the main class

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. The reason I add it in menuItem is because I have a pan effect on the menuItem, allowing the user to "drag" the menuItem from the menu to the scene. This is when I instantiate the sprite to the viewController. I already have it working where I can add the subview no problem, figuring out how to access the body subview would mean I only have to affect this one line of code. Thanks